# Dynamic insert PDO in missing fields

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using `PDO` for insert data into the database. All working pretty good, but I have a bit problem. Let me show you as an example,

```
//Perform a basic insert 

$param contains the fields that must be inserted
$this->insert("user", array("id" => $param['id'], "name" => $param['name']));
```

Now this insert working perfect, but suppose that In the `param` array missing the field `$name` I'll get the notice:

> Undefined Index `name`

how I can pass directly the fields to be insert? In my array the keys rapresents the column name, so: `id, name` and the value is the content to insert into the db.

This is my insert method:

```
public function insert($table, $data)
{
    $fieldNames = implode("`, `", array_keys($data));         
    $fieldValues = ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($data));  

    $sth = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (`$fieldNames`)
            VALUES ($fieldValues)");

    // Bind sui valori

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $sth->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }

    return $sth->execute();
}
```

How can I insert only the value that I need without passing all the fields and fall in error?

Answer (score 7):

Your error has nothing to do with the function you are using. It's only related to the way you're calling it.

*All* you need is just calling it like this:

```
$this->insert("user", $param);
```

And your existing code will take care for all the missing fields all right.

Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, see [The most fatal PDO code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example)

Comment: Can you fix the link in your answer? I'd be interested to read it if it still exists. Maybe you have an updated version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code (fields - is just array with fields name to save)

```
// $param - array with parameters
// $fields - fields which we want to save, e.g. array('id', 'name')
$param = array_filter($param, function($k) use ($fields) {
    return in_arrray($k, $fields);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$this->insert("user", $param);
```

Comment: I can't do this in the insert? Should be better

Comment: Message `Undefined Index name` pops up before insert. You get it because use `array("id" => $param['id'], "name" => $param['name'])` where no index `name` into `$param` variable